# Unbalanced braces with newenvironment / NewEnviron

Tags: macros, environments, braces

I am trying to define an Environment `myEnv` s.t.

```
\begin{myEnv}
text1
\end{myEnv} text2}
```

expands to

```
\renewcommand{\myCommand}{
text1
} { text2}
```

The reason for the obviously unbalanced expression in the first code sample is the limited capability of LyX when it comes to defining macro parameters over multiple paragraphs - I have to cope with it at the moment. I've already tried

```
\NewEnviron{myEnv}{\expandafter\newcommand\csname myCommand \endcsname{\BODY} \bgroup}
```

however, this isn't working at all.

**Edit:**
Based on egreg's answer, I give a minimal, non-working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\myCommand}{}

\NewEnviron{myEnv}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\myCommand\expandafter{\BODY}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnv}
text1
\end{myEnv} text2}

testing \myCommand testing

\end{document}
```

which gives the error

```
! Too many }'s.
l.13 \end{myEnv} text2}
```

The expected document output would be

```
text2 testing text1 testing
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what the role of `{text1}` and `{text2}` is, as apparently `\myCommand` is defined *without* arguments. Do you need to *define* a command or to *use* it?

Comment: Yes, `\myCommand` is defined without arguments - it is just a textual definition. I really need to define a command here; the code given above is really what I want to achieve. Note that this construction is only necessary to circumvent some nasty habits of LyX.

Comment: So, what `\renewcommand{\myCommand}{<n>text1<n>}{ text2}` (`<n>` stands for the new line) should mean? However, if you want to say `\renewcommand{\myCommand}{<n>text1<n>}`, you only need to say `\renewcommand{\myCommand}{ text1 }` (a new line there is exactly like a space).

Comment: Please observe that there is a whitespace before the `{ text2}`. Thus the resulting code is `\renewcommand{\myCommand}{<n>text1<n>} { text2}`. This redefines `myCommand` and then simply emits `text2` as normal text. `text2` is not in any way part of the command definition!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myEnv}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\myCommand\expandafter{\BODY}}
```

It's however quite difficult to understand what you need to achieve. If you want to write multiple paragraphs, you can simply say

```
\newcommand{\myCommand}{text of first paragraph\par text of second paragraph\par}
```

In order to cope with the bizarre syntax you want to use, then

```
\NewEnviron{myEnv}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\myCommand\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \aftergroup\bgroup}
```

will work. But it's always difficult to understand what you *really* need.

Comment: Yup, the code from your last edit works! Thank you very much!